# What are the atomic guarantees on copying a folder in GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a GCS bucket containing a directory `my-bucket-name/my-temp-dir-name`. This directory contains many subfiles. I would like to execute a copy command, e.g. `gsutil cp gs://my-bucket-name/my-temp-dir-name gs://my-bucket-name/my-dir-name`.

Are there any atomic guarantees around this operation? Is it possible that some files will be accessible in `my-dir-name` before all the files are available? What if `my-dir-name` already exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Individual object copies are atomic, but GCS does not support atomicity of copies across multiple objects.

Comment: Any authoritative documentation that could be linked, to corroborate?

Comment: object replace/update is atomic as well ? Is it delete + copy ?

Comment: Ashika Umanga Umagiliya yes, overwriting, deleting, and copying objects are all atomic operations, as is updating an object's metadata. An object's data can't be updated, but you can overwrite an object with a new generation, and that overwrite is atomic as well.

Answer (score 1):

`your-dir-name` must exist before copying, otherwise the `cp` operation will result in a 404 when trying to locate the bucket.

Objects are copied independently (one at a time, or in parallel, depending on whether you super-power `gsutil` with the `-m` flag). Therefore, files will start to appear in `your-dir-name` as soon as they make it up to the cloud.

Note that objects in GCS are immutable, and operations are atomic at the object level. This means that the latest uploaded object wins: replaces the previous one(s). If you are interested in keeping previous version, you can enable [versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning), and a N number of copies will be kept.

**Bonus:** If you are copying multiple files at once, use the `-m` flag to upload more than one object at the same time, like so:

`gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-bucket-name/my-temp-dir-name gs://my-bucket-name/my-dir-name`
or
`gsutil -m cp gs://my-bucket-name/my-temp-dir-name/* gs://my-bucket-name/my-dir-name`